# Can't login to Facebook due to invalid access token error using Titanium's Facebook Module

Tags: android, facebook, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I'm working with Titanium Studio 3.2.0 and Titanium SDK 3.2.0.GA, and deploying to Android devices with or without the Facebook app. To login to Facebook I'm using [the one provided by Titanium](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Modules.Facebook).

I'm having the same problem described in [this link](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/156426/facebook-module---invalid-access-token-on-android-23x). When I authorize for the first time, the log in event from Facebook is fired with no problem at all. But if I log out and then try to authorize again(at this point my app's permissions have been already accepted so in theory it should fire the login event) I get the following error on logcat:

```
E/FacebookModule( 1584): (main) [11631,11631] LoginDialogListener onFacebookError: Invalid access token.
E/FacebookModule( 1584): com.facebook.android.FacebookError: Invalid access token.
E/FacebookModule( 1584):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.onSessionCallback(Facebook.java:433)
E/FacebookModule( 1584):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.access$000(Facebook.java:97)
E/FacebookModule( 1584):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook$2.call(Facebook.java:379)
E/FacebookModule( 1584):    at com.facebook.Session$3$1.run(Session.java:1239)
E/FacebookModule( 1584):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
E/FacebookModule( 1584):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/FacebookModule( 1584):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
E/FacebookModule( 1584):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
E/FacebookModule( 1584):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/FacebookModule( 1584):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/FacebookModule( 1584):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
E/FacebookModule( 1584):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
E/FacebookModule( 1584):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/FacebookModule( 1584): (main) [6,11637] onAuthFail: Invalid access token.
```

I even tried to catch this error with a try/catch to handle it, but even though I placed the authorize call inside one, the code inside the catch didn't get executed. There's nothing unusual on how I do the authorization as far as I know:

```
$.LoginButtonHolder.addEventListener('singletap', function(e) {
        $.activityIndicator.show();
        $.LoginButtonLabel.setOpacity(0);
        try
        {
            fb.authorize();
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            // if the authorize call fails, show the error on the console and show the controls to try again
            // but these four lines of code never get executed, an unhandled exception is still thrown
            Ti.API.info('error in Facebook login');
            Ti.API.info(err);
            $.activityIndicator.hide();
            $.LoginButtonLabel.setOpacity(1);
        }
});
```

After some digging I realized something, the first time I try to authorize I get redirected to the Facebook app and after accepting the permissions, the login event is fired like it should (as proof of it I get an access token), when I logout the access token that was used for the session is nullified (I checked it in the logout event), then if I try to authorize again it seems the Facebook module isn't reaching out for a new access token, even though my app is already allowed, it's trying to use the nullified one, hence throwing this Invalid access token, **although this is only a guess from my part and I have no idea if this is the cause**.

How can I solve this problem? The solution I'm using at the moment is to remove the permissions from my Facebook user account through a Graph api call, which is not the correct way but it's the only way for me to fire the Facebook login event again.

Also I checked my hash keys and they seem to be in order since I get no invalid hash key message, the issue here is the access token, the authorize call should return an access token with a different expiration as far as I know, or did I got the wrong idea?.

According to this [Facebook developers link](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/%E2%80%8B), there are four scenarios when an access token expires, but for the log out scenario I get a different error message, the error message shown there is *Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out*, while the one I get is *LoginDialogListener onFacebookError: Invalid access token*. What is causing the error message I'm getting?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you still get this error if you have no facebook app present in the phone?

Comment: No, but I need to use the facebook app login in case it's installed. I guess the main problem is with Titanium use of Activities, but other people seem  to have no problem with it.

Comment: same problem with phonegap. i manage to come up with diffrent solution. before calling the fb.authorize, i'm checking if a specific localStorage item is exists, if not, i do the authorization and then set a new localStorage item . if yes - i handle him like he is logged  in, because i know he's logged in because of the localStorage item.
see localStorage - http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: what specific item are you looking for? Also isn't phonegap more restricted than Titanium SDK in terms of development complexity?

Answer (score 0):

I use this to clear out any residual Facebook user data when a user logs out, Not sure how Titanium uses the Facebook SDK, but this is how I do it with stock FB SDK.

```
    Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
```